# Internal working and connection of Kubernetes Ingress Object and Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I was trying to understand the relation between `Kubernetes` `Ingress Resource` and `Ingress Controller`.
I read that `Ingress` resource is mainly the rules and controller Pods route the traffic actually for Ingress rules.

I'm confused, like other Objects why `Ingress` resource can not spin up PODs on its own by specifying the image.

Secondly, how `Ingress Object` connects to actual `Ingress Controller Pods` to get its work done ( or say other way round). I don't see specifying any selector in the `Ingress Object`.

Thirdly, if the `Ingress Resource` gets its own IP address ( internal or external) then why `Ingress Controller` needs external IP address.

thanks

PS: I do not have a great knowledge of Kubernetes, please pardon if the questions sound silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Details with diagram are posted in GKE tutorial
[Ingress with NGINX controller on Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke)